# How to Rotate a square

Tags: python, arrays, list

Im having a hard time with the logic of the function def rotate: for example If I have a square of 3x3

```
0 5 2   
7 8 4   
1 6 3
```

and I rotate it:
Up on 2nd row

```
0   5   4   
7   8   3   
1   6   2
```

Down on  2nd

```
0   5   2   
7   8   4   
1   6   3
```

Left on 1st row- not sure its right but

```
0   5   2   
8   4   7   
1   6   3
```

Down on 2nd row

```
0 5 3
8 4 2
1 6 7
```

the final rotation should be

```
0 5 3
8 4 2
1 6 7
```

but i get rotation

```
0 5 4   
8 4 2   
1 6 2
```

below is are my function> if someone can help out with an error that would be great

```
def rotate(torusSquare,direction,index):
    if(direction=='L' and index<3):
        vals=torusSquare[index]
        temp=vals[0]
        vals[0]=vals[1]
        vals[1]=vals[2]
        vals[2]=temp
        torusSquare[index]=vals
    elif(direction=='R' and index<3):
         vals=torusSquare[index]
         temp=vals[2]
         vals[2]=vals[1]
         vals[1]=vals[0]
         vals[0]=temp
         torusSquare[index]=vals
    elif(direction=='U' and index<3):
         temp=torusSquare[0][index]
         torusSquare[0][index]=torusSquare[1][index]
         torusSquare[1][index]=torusSquare[2][index]
         torusSquare[2][index]=temp
    elif(direction=='D' and index<3):
          temp=torusSquare[2][index]
          torusSquare[1][index]=torusSquare[0][index]
          torusSquare[2][index]=torusSquare[1][index]
          torusSquare[0][index]=temp
def readfile(x):
    torusSquare=[]
    file= open(x)
    count=0
    maxcount=0
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if count<3:
            line=line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
            vals=[]
            for val in line:
                vals.append(int(val))
            torusSquare.append(vals)
            count+=1
        elif count==3:
            maxcount=int(line.rstrip('\n'))
            print("Before The Rotation")
            for i in range(count):
                for j in range(count):
                    print(torusSquare[i][j],' ',end=' ')
                print()
            count+=1
        elif maxcount>0:
            line=line.rstrip('\n')
            lst=line.split(' ')
            rotate(torusSquare,lst[0],int(lst[1]))
            maxcount-=1
        elif maxcount==maxcount:
            print("After The Final Rotation")
            for i in range(3):
                for j in range(3):
                    print(torusSquare[i][j],' ',end=' ')
                print()
            break
```

Comment: Can you type the expected output after each of these steps `Up on 2nd row Down on 2nd Left on 1st row Down on 2nd row`

Comment: Hey, Shubham. For sure, I'll make an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in the misnumbering of the indices, try switching your down section to the following:

```
    elif(direction=='D'):
        temp=torusSquare[2][index]
        torusSquare[2][index]=torusSquare[1][index]
        torusSquare[1][index]=torusSquare[0][index]
        torusSquare[0][index]=temp
```